# jQuery ajaxStart, ajaxStop Awkward Behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, fade

I've made this to illustrate my issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/michaelhart/mUMHZ/

(Only tested in Chrome.)

In summary: I don't want the ajax activity indicator to go crazy when users tab away and come back.

I've tried

```
$("#notification").clearQueue();
$("#notification").hide();

$("#notification").clearQueue();
$("#notification").show();
```

before

```
$('#notification').fadeOut();
```

but that just makes the indicator stop functioning completely after a tab out.

I'm not sure if this is a bug in the way Google Chrome handles inactive tabs or in the way jQuery works when Chrome puts it to "sleep."

Any ideas?

Comment: @Michael Hart — you [licensed your question to Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing) so you have no grounds to make such a demand. You also got useful information out of it, and Tak invested time giving you that information. Denying it to other people hardly seems reasonable.

Comment: @Michael: I think the reasoning here is that the answer provided to your question may prove valuable to the community, so it shouldn't be erased. If you really want it gone, I guess you'll have to get in touch with a moderator somehow (maybe chat, maybe meta). I'm not one, so I can't really help you. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [bug is noted](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9381) in the jQuery bug tracker. The suggested fix is to, instead of using setInterval blindly, use the callback function of the animation to trigger restart with a setTimeout.

E.g.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    fetchAjax();
});

function fetchAjax() {
        var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10001);
        $('#number').html(randomnumber);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/echo/html/',
            data: {
              'html': randomnumber
            },
            dataType: 'text/html'
        });
}

$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    $('#notification').fadeIn();
}).ajaxStop(function(){
    $('#notification').fadeOut(function(){
      setTimeout(function(){ fetchAjax(); }, 5*1000);
    });
});
```